# Not able to sign zip file using pkcs#7 and bouncyCastle in java

Tags: java, bouncycastle, zip, pkcs#7

I have a program to sign and verify text and zip files using pkcs#7 and bouncycastle. 
Am writing the following string into both text and zip files( which contains base64 encoded original data, SignedBytes and Certificate data) :

```
String finalmsg="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\" ?>\n" +
                     "<Envelope>\n" +"    <OrgContent>"+new String(Base64.encode(contentbytes))+"</OrgContent>\n"+"    <Signature>"+new String(Base64.encode(signedBytes))+"</Signature>\n"+"    <Certificate>"+
                    new String(Base64.encode(keyStore.getCertificate("CertName").getEncoded()))+"</Certificate>\n"+"</Envelope>";
```

Am able to verify my text file perfectly after signing. Also am able to verify my zip file but am not able to extract the zip file ( am getting unexpected end of zip file error)

Below is the code am using to write my signed message into the files :

```
if(file.getName().contains(".zip")) {
byte[] b = finalmsg.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
try (BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(address+"SIGVERFILES/s2/"+name), 4096)) {
    out.write(b);
}
} else {
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(address+"SIGVERFILES/s2/"+name,true);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    bw.write(finalmsg);
    bw.close();
}
```

Also am able to verify and unzip successfully zip files signed by other parties. So my verification code is fine. I think somethings wrong with the way am writing the zip file.
Please dont mind the indentation and request you to help me try to find out what am doing wrong here?

Please let me know if anymore code snippets are required.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just write a XML string into a file, rename it to "whatever.zip", and expect the result to be a valid zip file. Zip is a binary file format with its own constraints, one of them being the magic number starting with "PK" at the beginning of the file.

Exchanging signed data also has its own constraints, and [PKCS#7 SignedData](http://www.pkiglobe.org/pkcs7.html) is also a normalized format.

To make your life easier, BouncyCastle provides helper classes to generate valid, properly wrapped signed data. Check out their documentation and examples [here](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/cms/CMSSignedData.html) and [here](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.4/org/bouncycastle/cms/CMSSignedDataGenerator.html).

You will want to decide between generating an attached or detached signature : with an attached signature, the ASN.1 structure contains the signed message, so you can read validate the signature and read the payload from the same data block (example : RSA certificates). With a detached signature, it'll be up to you to transmit the data and its signature separately (but the recipiend will need both in order to verify the signature - example : signed files available for download on a public FTP server). Usually the question is answered simply by asking yourself if the recipient may want to use the payload without verifying its signature first, or not.